# How often does NuGet package gets updated?

Tags: nuget

I'm using NuGet to manage libraries used in my solution. But I wonder how often the libraries inside NuGet gets updated. For example, on 10 April 2019, jQuery 3.4.0 has been released, but as of today, the latest jQuery package on NuGet is more than 1 year old.

```
3.3.1   2,970,912   1/22/2018
```

I need to manually download the jQuery library from their website in order to use the latest version, but this beats the advantage of using NuGet. So my question is that how often is this updated? Is someone from Microsoft needs to add the library manually every time? Or does the library developer has to push the updates to NuGet (and I wonder why they have not done so if this is the case - now is more than 2 weeks after release date)?

Comment: It depends on the owner of the package, not Microsoft (unless they are one and the same).

Comment: I believe that the ASP.NET team no longer recommend using NuGet for javascript dependencies. They created [LibMan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/libman/libman-vs?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for basic usage, otherwise you should use npm or whatever the javascript ecosystem's trend of the day is. I feel like most of the ASP.NET community have stopped using javascript NuGet packages as well.